# Метод split не находит пробел в списке

Tags: javascript, split, indexof

В объекте есть свойство `className`, которое содержит список «классов» – слов, разделенных пробелом.Создайте функцию `addClass(obj, cls)`, которая добавляет в список класс `cls`, но только если его там еще нет.

1. Разбиваю список в объекте методом `split` по (' '),а он отказывается этот пробел находить..
2. Актуальна ли проверка на наличие класса в списке через метод indexOf?Или надо проводить сравнение `arr[i]==cls` ?

```js
function addClass(obj, cls) {
  var arr = obj.className.split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!!(~arr.indexOf(cls))) {
      return;
    }
  }
  arr.push(cls);

  obj.className = arr.join(' ');
}

var obj = {
  className: 'open menu'
}

addClass(obj, 'new');
addClass(obj, 'open');
addClass(obj, 'me');

console.log(obj.className);
```

Comment: После исправления ошибки в условии - твой код теперь тоже работает

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в использовании метода [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

1. этот метод возвращает **индекс** найденного элемента, либо -1, если элемент не найден. Поэтому проверка `!!(arr.indexOf(cls))` работает не так как ты ожидаешь.
2. этот метод уже проходит по массиву - нет нужды делать отдельный цикл.

Исходя из этого код можно исправить так:

```js
function addClass(obj, cls) {
  var arr = obj.className.split(' ');
  if (arr.indexOf(cls) == -1) {
    arr.push(cls);

    obj.className = arr.join(' ');
  }
}

var obj = {
  className: 'open menu'
}

addClass(obj, 'new');
addClass(obj, 'open');
addClass(obj, 'me');

console.log(obj.className);
```

Comment: ах вот оно, что...  понял...

Comment: Спасибо,но я там в методе забыл добавить ~ что бы смысл проверки был,что совпадение есть..но,а счёт того что метод indexOf  возвращает  число, я ведь поставил !! что гарантирует что  число будет преобразовано в булево значение...В  правильном ответе было сказано что проверка  через == верна,по причине  того,что метод indexOf найдёт cls = "menu" в массиве arr = ['open', 'mymenu'].

Comment: @user275236, здесь нет других ответов :-) в любом случае. ты путаешь **два разных** метода: [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) и [`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) - в твоем случае ты используешь первый, и с параметром сравнивается **целый элемент**. Ошибка была бы, если бы ты не использовал `split`, а сразу вызывал `indexOf` на свойстве `className`

Comment: я понял свою ошибку.. данный метод не подходит по заданию.. там указано,что надо добавить класс,если его нет в списке, а данный метод посчитает, что класс  menu уже есть в списке(или массиве,тут особой роли не играет)  open mymenu , а это не верно,поэтому нужно использовать сравнение == в качестве проверки на наличие класса

Comment: @user275236, ты не прав. Просто попробуй :-) Обрати внимание, что даже в приведенном снипете класс `me` отлично добавляется несмотря на присутствие класса `menu`.

Comment: @user275236, _данный метод посчитает, что класс menu уже есть в списке(или массиве,тут особой роли не играет)_ - на самом деле именно тут это играет большую роль, идет проверка в строке или в массиве.

Comment: всё теперь точно понял,в случае с массивом это прокатит,а в случае со строкой-нет